# Redux architecture for same-component reusability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

### TLDR:

An app has **N** number of `<Counter>` components, and one wishes to reflect each of the counters' state in the app's *Redux* store.

---

### Some context:

For the sake of this context, each counter represent time a player has
taken to  play his turn in a game with a dynamic number of players.

It is required also, when changing a player's turn, to pause all the other players' timers, and when restarting the game, all timers should be restarted to their initial state (`0ms`).

---

(I am using the [ducks](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) design-pattern for my *redux* code)

### timer.reducer.js

```js
let timerIdx = 0;

// timer "constructor"
function timer(){
    const TICK    = `game/timer${timerIdx}/TICK`
    const RESTART = `game/timer${timerIdx}/RESTART`

    let value = 0;

    // reducer
    const reducer = (state = 0, action = {}) => {
        switch( action.type ){
            case TICK :
                value = action.value; // update local state
                return action.value

            case RESTART :
                return 0
        }
        return state
    }

    const actionCreators = {
        start(dispatch) {
            const startTime = performance.now(),
                  lastValue = this.value;

            function tick(){
                dispatch({ 
                    type   : TICK, 
                    player : +player, 
                    value  : lastValue + performance.now() - startTime 
                })
            }

            tick();
            this.interval = setInterval(tick, 100);

            return this.interval;
        },
        stop(){
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.interval = null;
        },
        restart() {
            return { type:RESTART }
        }
    }

    timerIdx++;

    return {
        reducer,
        ...actionCreators
    }
}

export default timer;
```

### index.js (main reducer)

```js
import board from './board.reducer';
import timer from './timer.reducer';

export const timer1 = timer();
export const timer2 = timer();

const { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} = Redux;

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    board,
    timer1 : timer1.reducer,
    timer2 : timer2.reducer
});

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer
)
```

---

Initially I wrapped the `timer` reducer (above) in a function which returns a timer reducer "instance" (not a real instance) and encapsulate the whole "duck" thing in its own context. The usage of this thinking is shown in the above `index.js` file (`timer1` & `timer2`).

This isn't very robust because it requires me to know in advance how many counters should be created, and to hard-code them into the main reducer..

**How should such a scenario be designed in React-Redux architecture?**

Comment: I think that reducer should contain `timers` collection. And each <Counter> component could filter `timers` collection from Redux state by unique ID. In that case, you'll have only one `timers` reducer with all data inside.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh - originally this is **exactly** what I've made. a singly **counter** reducer and it's value was an array (item per user), but I did not like this idea of having a reducer being aware there are multiple players. I prefer the counter reducer to be stand-alone so I could re-use it also in other projects

Answer (score 0):

Sebastien Lorber raised this question soon after Redux came out.  He eventually created a repo, [slorber/scalable-frontend-with-elm-or-redux](https://github.com/slorber/scalable-frontend-with-elm-or-redux), which collects user-submitted examples of solutions to this kind of problem written with different implementations.

There is no single answer to this question, but I'd encourage you to look at that repo for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat similar to the issue of the 'todo app' in the redux examples. (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos).
I'd suggest that you keep a single reducer responsible for the timers and active player turn instead of one per player, since the reducer function will be the same for all of them. When the player dispatches the action telling to update its counter, it also needs to specify in the action what's that player id, and you can check if the active player is matching the id of the player dispatching the action then update that id in the state, otherwise ignore it. Your state would be something like this:

```
{
  count: {
    '0': 1,
    '1': 0,
    '2': 3
  },
  activePlayer: 2,
  amountOfPlayers: 3,
}
```

(Or use array-index instead of an key-value if you prefer)
And your action would be something like:

```
{
  type: 'TICK',
  playerId: id
}
```

And your reducer:

```
const myReducer = (state = {}, action = {}) => {
    switch( action.type ){
        case TICK :
            if(action.playerId !== state.activePlayer) {
              return state; // ignore tick actions coming from players that are not the active one
            }

            return Object.assign({},
                state,
                count: {
                  [action.playerId]: state.count[action.playerId]+1
                }
              }
            }
        case RESTART :
            return {
              ...state,
              {
                count: Object.assign({},
                  state.count,
                  {[action.playerId]: 0})
              }
            }
        }
        case ADD_PLAYER:
          return Object.assign({},
            state,
            {amountOfPlayers: state.amountOfPlayers+1},
            {
              count: Object.assign({},
               state.count,
               {[state.amountOfPlayers]: 0}
              })
            }
          );
    return state;
}
```

And finally, if you need to map your state to props, just grab from count using the id of that player. Probably the reducer can be written better but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a kind of keyed reducer, like so:

```js
const createKeyedReducer = ({
  targetReducer,
}) => {
  const ALL = 'KEYED_ALL'
  const RESET = 'KEYED_RESET'
  const ONE = 'KEYED_ONE'
  const keyedReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case RESET:
        // might wanna use lodash.mapValues here
        return Object.keys(state).reduce((prev, key) => {
          prev[key] = targetReducer(undefined, { type: '@@redux/init'})
          return prev
        }, {})
      case ALL:
        return Object.keys(state).reduce((prev, key) => {
          prev[key] = targetReducer(state[key], action.action)
          return prev
        }, {})
      case ONE:
        return {
          ...state,
          // unpack action.action
          [action.routingKey]: targetReducer(state[action.routingKey], action.action)
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  return {
    reducer: keyedReducer,
    keyedAll: action => ({ type: ALL, action }),
    keyedReset: () => ({ type: RESET }),
    keyedOne: (routingKey, action) => ({ type: ONE, routingKey, action }),
  }
}
```

Your timer reducer would be kept isolated.